# Getting records with the most number of occurrences of a string in a field

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

```
Videos Table

Title          date_published
food bag       2011-01-01
bear food bag  2010-02-02
bag mouse      2000-03-03
monitor mouse  2002-03-03
```

My question is what SQL statement could extract a list of records with the most number of occurrences of `food` in the `title` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of times a string occurs with a `replace` trick:

```
select  len(replace(title,'food','food+')) - len(title) as FoodCount
from    Videos
```

This adds an extra character for each occurrence, and then counts how many extra characters were added.

This SQL Server query selects the top 10 videos with most food:

```
select  top 10 *
from    (
        select  *
        ,       len(replace(title,'food','food+')) - len(title) as FoodCount
        from    Videos
        ) as SubQueryAlias
order by
        FoodCount desc
```

For MySQL, you'd remove the `top 10` and add `limit 10` at the end.

Comment: Andomar, how'd you do it if I need to find the one with the most occurrences of food AND bag.

Comment: @Thorpe Obazee: You can do that with a double replace: `replace(replace(title,'food','food+'),'bag','bag+')`